# nested json from s3 to dataframe with pandas

Tags: json, pandas, amazon-s3, json-normalize

I'm struggling to unnest this json, pulling from s3, and store only parts of it within a dataframe.

here is the structure

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
dat = []
content_object = s3.Object(FROM_BUCKET, key['Key'])
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
json_content

output:
{'twts': {'101861193645447': {'aiScrs': [{'lfeEvtId': 5,
     'orgScr': 0.779,
     'adjScr': 0.3865,
     'lstScrUtc': '2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z',
     'lstScrYmd': '2021-02-24'}]},
  '100300192097235': {'aiScrs': [{'lfeEvtId': 5,
     'orgScr': 0.765,
     'adjScr': 0.365,
     'lstScrUtc': '2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z',
     'lstScrYmd': '2021-02-24'}]},
  '100179311336977': {'aiScrs': [{'lfeEvtId': 5,
     'orgScr': 0.732,
     'adjScr': 0.332,
     'lstScrUtc': '2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z',
     'lstScrYmd': '2021-02-24'}]}}}
```

here is my attempt

```
df_dat=[]
dat =[]
response = s3_c.get_object(Bucket=FROM_BUCKET, Key=key['Key'])
df_dat = pd.read_json(response['Body'],convert_axes=False)
df_dat
dat = pd.json_normalize(data=df_dat)
dat

output:

twts
100179311336977 {'aiScrs': [{'lfeEvtId': 5, 'orgScr': 0.732, 'adjScr': 0.332, 'lstScrUtc': '2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z', 'lstScrYmd': '2022-02-24'}]}
100300192097235 {'aiScrs': [{'lfeEvtId': 5, 'orgScr': 0.765, 'adjScr': 0.365, 'lstScrUtc': '2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z', 'lstScrYmd': '2022-02-24'}]}
101861193645447 {'aiScrs': [{'lfeEvtId': 5, 'orgScr': 0.779, 'adjScr': 0.3865, 'lstScrUtc': '2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z', 'lstScrYmd': '2022-02-24'}]}

this last part errors out 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-0d22f901897d> in <module>
      4 df_dat = pd.read_json(response['Body'],convert_axes=False)
      5 df_dat
----> 6 dat = pd.json_normalize(data=df_dat)
      7 # dat = pd.json_normalize(data=df_dat, record_path=['aiScrs'])
      8 dat

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    268 
    269     if record_path is None:
--> 270         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
    271             # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
    272             # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for

~/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    268 
    269     if record_path is None:
--> 270         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
    271             # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
    272             # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

it errors out when i try to manipulate it in anyway, including

```
dat = pd.json_normalize(data=df_dat, record_path=['aiScrs'])
```

i'm trying to get out 3 rows, with all the below columns

```
ID   lfeEvtId orgScr adjScr lstScrUtc lstScrYmd
X
X
X...
```

i cannot seem to find a way to do this (with json_normalize would be preferrable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some list-comprehension to shape `json_content` into a more usable structure. Then `pd.json_normalize` is simple to use

```
tweet_json_list = [{'id': k, **v} for k, v in json_content['twts'].items()]
df = pd.json_normalize(tweet_json_list, record_path='aiScrs', meta=['id'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   lfeEvtId  orgScr  adjScr                     lstScrUtc   lstScrYmd               id
0         5   0.779  0.3865  2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z  2021-02-24  101861193645447
1         5   0.765  0.3650  2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z  2021-02-24  100300192097235
2         5   0.732  0.3320  2021-02-24T22:14:17.8420665Z  2021-02-24  100179311336977
```

Comment: very useful thx you.  why does it need that manipulation? is there a way to do it without that manipulation, right as you load it in?

Comment: I'm not really sure, unfortunately. `json_normalize` wants a list, but your data is a dict.